# How do I wrap DLL functions that are member functions?

Tags: c++, function, dll, wrapper

I am creating a wrapper class that wraps a bunch of functions outlined in a particular 3rd party API.  When I try to wrap non-member functions like this:

**(AVTcamDllWrapper.h)**

```
typedef VmbErrorType (WINAPI * AVTGETCAMERAS) (CameraPtrVector cameras);

class CAVTcamDllWrapper
{
    HMODULE mAVTCamLibrary; //I later have this point to the DLL

public:
    void AVTGetCameras (CameraPtrVector cameras);
};
```

**(AVTcamDllWrapper.cpp)**

```
void CAVTcamDllWrapper::AVTGetCameras(AVTNS CameraPtrVector cameras)
{

    AVTGETCAMERAS   pFunc = NULL;

    pFunc = (AVTGETCAMERAS) GetProcAddress(mAVTCamLibrary, "?GetCameras@VimbaSystem@VmbAPI@AVT@@AEAA?AW4VmbErrorType@@PEAV?$shared_ptr@VCamera@VmbAPI@AVT@@@23@AEAI@Z");
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    if(pFunc == NULL)
    {
        Exlog(L"CAVTcamDllWrapper::AVTGetCameras: Failed to locate AVTGetCameras method in AVTCamera DLL.");
        NIERR_SET_AND_THROW_ERROR(NIERR_CAMERA_ERROR, L"Failed to locate AVTGetCameras method in AVTCamera DLL.");
    }
    VmbErrorType vErr = pFunc(cameras);

    if(vErr != VmbErrorSuccess)
    {
        wstring exLogMsg = Format(exLogMsg, L"CAVTcamDllWrapper::AVTGetCameras(): Failed to get any cameras.  VmbErrorType = %d", vErr);
        Exlog(exLogMsg.c_str());

        NIERR_SET_AND_THROW_ERROR(NIERR_CAMERA_ERROR, L"Failed to get any cameras.");
    }
}
```

The above code works great for non-member functions.  For example, if I am trying to wrap a function that is called simply by saying:

```
CallFunction(blah, blaaaaah);
```

then the wrapper class works fine, and the pFunc is set properly and no error occurs on the `VmbErrorType vErr = pFunc();` line;

However, many of my functions are member function, and are called like this:

```
SomeObject.CallMemberFunction(blah, bleh);

// or

SomeObjectPointer->CallMemberFunction(what, ever);
```

and these are the functions I can't seem to wrap.  The error occurs on the line:

```
VmbErrorType vErr = pFunc();
```

because the function cannot be called without a specific object to call it from.  In my example, I am wrapping a function GetCameras which exists inside of Camera.  Without wrapping the function, to call it I simply create a vector of Camera pointers, and do:

```
cameras[0]->GetCameras(VmbAccessModeFull);
```

which works.  But I have no idea how I would go about wrapping this function, as the call to GetCameras is both dependent on `cameras[0]` and completely useless without a camera to call it from.

***So how do I wrap member functions like the one shown above?***

---

**Edit 1:**

I have tried to pass in a reference to a specific object and do

```
VmbErrorType vErr = theObject->pFunc();
```

but obviously this won't work because then it will think to look for a function named pFunc inside of theObject, which doesn't exist.

---

**Edit 2:**

I feel like I would almost have modify the wrapper function to pass the reference object in as a parameter or something.  So like instead of the regular:

```
cameras[0]->GetCameras(VmbAccessModeFull);
```

I would have to modify some stuff and make my wrapper function look like this:

```
mWrapperObject->WrappedGetCameras(VmbAccessModeFull, cameras[0]);
```

so that the wrapped function will have the context it needs to act as a member function.

Comment: The member function may need to access the `this` pointer, e.g. for accessing member variables. If this is indeed the case, you *will* need some instance to call the method on.

Comment: But wouldn't that still produce an error, or rather, an incompilable program? It would look for a function named pFunc inside of whatever object `this` is referring to, and it won't find one, ex: if i passed in `this` as `theObject`, then I would do `VmbErrorType vErr = theObject->pFunc();`, which wouldn't compile because there is no pFunc function inside of theObject

Comment: For WINAPI decorated function, cameras[0] should be the first parameter.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Why not just wrap the origianl class with your wrapper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's done.  Say you have two layers: The member function layer and the wrapper function layer.  What you need to do is create a third layer that lies in between these two layers, and export this layer to a .dll file.  At first (back when I asked the question) I was trying to wrap functions that looked like this:

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunction(CString someParam)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

This didn't work because, as the question describes, you cannot wrap member functions.  What I discovered was that I needed to do all of the object management on a layer above the member function calls, but still below the wrapper functions.  What I ended up with was a bunch of "Bridge" functions (that's what I called them) that "bridge" the gap between the wrapper functions and the member functions.  So now, I wrapped functions that looked like this:

```
void BridgedSomeFunction(CString someParam)
{
    classObject.SomeFunction(someParam);
}
```

Then I simply did some `__declspec(dllexport)`'s and `__declspec(dllimport)`'s to turn these functions into a .dll file, and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

To call a member function you must have an object at hand. To have an object you must get it from somewhere. The only place a good little well-behaving function can get stuff from is its parameter list.

So each of your functions obviously must have a parameter that receives The Object.

If you want your wrapper functions to be callable from C, you cannot have class types as function parameters. So you either declare it as a `void*` and do a cast inside, or just cheat and type it (for C only!) `struct YourClassName*` (without ever defining the struct). For C++, it should still use the class keyword. Use the preprocessor.

In a nutshell,

```
foo->bar(moo, roo)
```

is the fancy shmancy C++ way of saying

```
FooType_bar(foo, moo, roo)
```

and you should think about wrapping the latter while actually spelling the former.

How the caller obtains The Object then? One of your functions could create objects (with `new`) and return pointers to them. Another one could do a delete. Or you can return pointers to elements of a pre-allocated array. Or whatever. Basically you wrap the ways you use to obtain pointers to objects as a user of the original, unwrapped library.

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the this pointer as first argument if you are calling memberfunctions and make sure you are using the right calling convention. For static member functions you don´t have to pass the this pointer.

On x64 you would not even have to worry about calling conventions, as everything will be compiled as __fastcall. No matter what calling convention you specify.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>


class Camera
{
    int i;
public:
    Camera()
    {
        i = 123;
    }


    void __stdcall print_1(int j, int k)
    {
        std::cout << i << j << k << std::endl;
    }

    void __cdecl print_2(int j, int k)
    {
        std::cout << i << j << k << std::endl;
    }

    void print_3(int j, int k)
    {
        std::cout << i << j << k << std::endl;
    }

    static void __cdecl print_s1(int j, int k)
    {
        std::cout << j << k << std::endl;
    }

    static void __stdcall print_s2(int j, int k)
    {
        std::cout << j << k << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Camera cam;
    Camera* pCam = &cam;

    // call __stdcall memberfunction
    typedef void (__stdcall* tprint_1)(Camera*,int,int);
    tprint_1 print_1 = (tprint_1)&Camera::print_1;
    print_1(pCam,1,2);

    // call __cdecl memberfunction
    typedef void (__cdecl* tprint_2)(Camera*,int,int);
    tprint_2 print_2 = (tprint_2)&Camera::print_2;
    print_2(pCam,3,4);

    // call __thiscall  memberfunction
    typedef void (__thiscall* tprint_3)(Camera*,int,int);
    tprint_3 print_3 = (tprint_3)&Camera::print_3;
    print_3(pCam,5,6);

    // call __thiscall  memberfunction different syntax
    typedef void (Camera::* tprint_4)(int,int);
    tprint_4 print_4 = (tprint_4)&Camera::print_3;
    (pCam->*print_4)(7,8);


    // static member functions don´t take a this pointer
    typedef void(__cdecl* tprint_s1)(int,int);
    tprint_s1 print_s1 = (tprint_s1)&Camera::print_s1;
    print_s1(9,10);

    // static member functions don´t take a this pointer
    typedef void(__stdcall* tprint_s2)(int,int);
    tprint_s2 print_s2 = (tprint_s2)&Camera::print_s2;
    print_s2(11,12);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would passing in the `this` pointer work, though?  If you look at my implementation of a wrapper class, I am creating a pointer to the function I want to wrap called `pFunc`.  If I passed in a `this` pointer as, say, `pThis`, then what would I do with it?  If I tried to call pThis->pFunc, that would make my program uncompilable since I have no function in pThis named pFunc.

Comment: you can either call it like

Comment: you can not pass the thispointer of the wrapper class. you will have to pass a this pointer to an object who´s method you want to call. That´s the first argument in my examples. As you can not directly call pThis->pFunc, you have to pass pThis as first argument like in print_1 to _3. Or use the syntax of the print_4 example. _3 and _4 are the same just with different syntax for the typedef and call

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converthing the thiscall for memberfunctions to a fastcall

http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/73849-thiscall-hooking.html